# deep meaning of 女生

Tags: translation

i'm trying to figure out the meaning of the term 女生.

I was told it's something deeper than "school girl"/"student girl"/not married"/"beauty"  or
anything like that.

I know that in separated one means birth and the other means female or woman but together..

Would appreciate your help on translating.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please confirm if you mean 姓 or 女生. Can you also edit your question to show a problem that is not answered by a standard dictionary. If you are having a particular problem that cannot be answered by a dictionary please edit your question and then use "flag" to request a moderator to review.

Answer (score 6):

女生 just means girl. If you are an English speaker, ask yourself what is the deep meaning of girl and that will answer this question. There isn't a deep meaning in every single Chinese word/phrase.

Comment: my teacher said it means: family name. that mothers give their family name to their children

Comment: I am sorry to say your teacher is wrong. Children take on their father's family name so that doesn't make any sense.

Comment: No, OP's teacher is correct when it is a historical topic. See [姓](http://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%A7%93) and [氏](http://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%B0%8F).

Comment: @Stan, I see my mistake. OP wrote 女生, which I perceived to be separate characters meaning girl or female. 姓  is a different story.

Answer (score 1):

It simply means girl, not necessary to stand for students or adolescents.

Answer (score 1):

In mainland China, 女生 refers to school girls，in Taiwan 女生 refers to school girls and the girls who haven’t married yet